# Limit of labels on a node in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, database-performance

Is there a limit on the number of labels you can put on nodes in Neo4j?
Also what are the ramifications of lots of labels on the performance of inserts?
Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In theory the number of labels is almost unlimited (not sure but I think it was Integer.MAX_VALUE). In practice you should have as few labels as reasonable on a single node. The first 4-5 (don't remember the exact number) labels are stored directly with the node. The remaining labels are stored in a different location internally. So reading a node having more than 4-5 labels might result in another IO operation.

Upon a write operation every labels will cause extra burden since labels are self-indexing and therefore Neo4j needs to write to the labelscanstore for that label.

Most graphs I've seen so far (and that's quire a few ;-) ) don't have more  than 3 labels on a single node.

Comment: Due to the complexity of our graph we are going to have up to 40 labels per node for certain sections of our graph ( I know this seems crazy, but we won't be able to get round this). Could you point me at any information on where/how the labels are stored for reading? This issue could be really important to us, I knew writing would be an issue, but didn't realize reading would be...

Comment: The first few labels (5 afaik) directly with the node in the neostore.nodestore.db. In case a node has more labels, they go to neostore.nodestore.db.labels. So for reading a node with lots of labels a second seek operation is needed. This is not a big performance hit, but is has some impact.

Comment: Hi @StefanArmbruster, I'm wondering if you have any source for the "4-5 labels are stored in the node" figure. I unfrotunately can't find any resource or documentation mentioning these figures